# arguments of a function or package filled sequentially from a data frame or list

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, lapply, rnoaa

I am using the new R package RNOAA to access climate data from NOAA and currently am doing it one time period at a time.  Like this.

```
PRCP_2002a<- ncdc(datasetid='GHCND', datatypeid ='PRCP', startdate = '2001-08-13', enddate = '2002-02-13', stationid='x', token = 'x', limit = 500)
```

I end up with a long list of the above code with many different start and stop dates entered manually with one line of code for each time period.  Is there a way to use a for loop and lapply or something similar with each start and stop date being grabbed from a data frame or list and the result object being named also from the list or data frame? 
I would presumably read a csv file like this in.

```
Periods <- read.csv("Climate_dates.csv")
         ID      Start       Stop
1 2002S 2001-08-13 2002-02-13
2 2002F 2002-04-02 2002-10-02
3 2003S 2002-09-19 2003-03-19
4 2003F 2003-04-22 2003-10-22
5 2004S 2003-09-30 2004-03-31
6 2004F 2004-04-20 2004-10-20
7 2005S 2004-09-23 2005-03-23
8 2005F 2005-04-26 2005-10-26
```

Then some method to refer to the dates and IDs sequentially as the for loop or lapply or whatever iterates through.

```
ID in Periods<- ncdc(datasetid='GHCND', datatypeid ='PRCP', startdate = 'Start in Periods', enddate = 'Stop in Periods', stationid='x', token = 'x', limit = 500)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Apologies for my R ineptitude.

Pierre suggested this solution however it appears not to be providing the start or end dates to the ncdc command.  Any thoughts?

```
mylst <- apply(Periods[-1], 1, function(x) ncdc(datasetid='GHCND', datatypeid     ='PRCP', startdate = x[1], enddate = x[2], stationid='x', token =     'x', limit = 500))

Warning messages:
1: Error: (400) - Required parameter 'startdate' is missing. 
2: Error: (400) - Required parameter 'startdate' is missing. 
3: Error: (400) - Required parameter 'startdate' is missing. 
4: Error: (400) - Required parameter 'startdate' is missing. 
5: Error: (400) - Required parameter 'startdate' is missing. 
6: Error: (400) - Required parameter 'startdate' is missing. 
7: Error: (400) - Required parameter 'startdate' is missing. 
8: Error: (400) - Required parameter 'startdate' is missing.
```

Comment: For those who do not have the package installed, please post some of the data in question and the desired result.

Comment: Try `mylst <- apply(Periods[-1], 1, function(x) ncdc(datasetid='GHCND', datatypeid ='PRCP', startdate = x[1], enddate = x[2], stationid='x', token = 'x', limit = 500))`. Then you can name it afterwards, `names(mylist) <- Periods[,1]`

Comment: it says on the NOAA website there is a 5 second time limit between requests, you might do better by just reading them in a loop, or defining a new function with a time delay and using apply

Comment: I really appreciate your help Pierre.  I think it's almost there.  As per edit above it seems the code you suggested is not getting the start or stop dates.  Any thoughts?  Should the code read startdate = x[2], enddate = x[3]